# Nonempty search queries don't work with the Soundcloud Python wrapper API

Tags: python, api, wrapper, soundcloud

Only empty search queries work with the Soundcloud Python wrapper API (GET calls). Otherwise, I get a "TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None"

```
gmail_users = client.get('/users', q='hello', limit=page_size)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?